# How to start a server from the command line in a Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, subprocess

I'm building a tester for a Python script which performs works with a RethinkDB database. As part of the `setUp()` method, I'm trying to make the tester start up the RethinkDB server on `localhost` on port `28016` in case that has not yet been done.

I'm using `subprocess` to start the server. The problem is that, according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html, `subprocess` waits for the command to complete. In this case, it seems that as long as the server is up and running, the process is not complete and testing does not continue beyond the `setUp()` stage.

Here is the script I'm trying:

```
import unittest
import rethinkdb as r
import subprocess

class TestController(unittest.TestCase):

    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT_OFFSET = 1
    PORT = 28015 + PORT_OFFSET
    DB = "ipercron"
    TABLE = "sensor_data"


    def setUp(self):
        try:
            self.conn = r.connect(self.HOST, self.PORT)
        except r.ReqlDriverError:
            print("The RethinkDB server is not yet ready. Starting it up...")
            subprocess.call(["rethinkdb", "--port-offset", str(TestController.PORT_OFFSET)])
            self.conn = r.connect(self.HOST, self.PORT)

        if TestController.DB not in r.db_list().run(self.conn):
            r.db_create(TestController.DB).run(self.conn)
            self.conn.use(TestController.DB)

        if TestController.TABLE not in r.table_list().run(self.conn):
            r.table_create(TestController.TABLE).run(self.conn)        # Create the table if it does not yet exist

        r.table(TestController.TABLE).delete().run(self.conn)          # Empty the table to start with a clean slate

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestController)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The `subprocess` is meant to perform the `rethinkdb --port-offset 1` command at the command line and then continue with the script. However, when I run the script I get the usual message that the server is ready:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/dev/clones/ipercron-compose/controller$ python unittest_controller.py
test_upper (__main__.TestController) ... The RethinkDB server is not yet ready. Starting it up...
Running rethinkdb 2.3.5~0xenial (GCC 5.3.1)...
Running on Linux 4.4.0-42-generic x86_64
Loading data from directory /home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-compose/controller/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29016
Listening for client driver connections on port 28016
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8081
Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
To fully expose RethinkDB on the network, bind to all addresses by running rethinkdb with the `--bind all` command line option.
Server ready, "kurt_ThinkPad_a0k" 07bb35f6-3a33-4e8b-9e9c-a78504457969
```

Without any further action. How can I make the unittest proceed with the testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as you said, that [`subprocess.call` is blocking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) and will wait for the command to finish. For scenarios where you need to spawn a child process without waiting for it to finish, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["rethinkdb", "--port-offset", str(TestController.PORT_OFFSET)])
```

This gives you back a [`Popen` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) that provides a whole bunch of very useful methods to communicate with the child process. For example, you will probably want to use `process.kill()` in your unit test's `tearDown()` function to shut down your database.

Comment: In order to make it work I had to put in a `time.sleep()` command to give the server time to get up and running. I don't suppose there is a way to wait till the server is running, for example by parsing the standard output?

Comment: `Popen` exposes an [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) file-like object that you could read from to wait until you see the server has booted up, but it might be a little bit tedious to implement. A simpler option might be to use something like [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), if you're ok with introducing a new dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code

```
subprocess.call(["rethinkdb", "--port-offset", str(TestController.PORT_OFFSET)], shell = True)
```